# Is there an indexing strategy in Postgres which will operate effectively for JOINs with ORs

Tags: jquery, sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query I’m attempting to optimise.

table1 has 300,000 rows and table2 has 100,000 rows

Each table has key columns (key1..key15)

I am attempting to select all rows in table1 and LEFT JOINing table2 on these matching keys.

I also have wildcard keys in table2 (designated ‘all’)

Here is a partial example of the join

```
SELECT 
  t1.*, 
  t2.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON 
(t1.key1 = t2.key1 OR t2.key1 = ‘all’) AND
(t1.key2 = t2.key2 OR t2.key2 = ‘all’) AND
(t1.key3 = t2.key3 OR t2.key3 = ‘all’) AND
(t1.key4 = t2.key4 OR t2.key4 = ‘all’) AND
(t1.key5 = t2.key5 OR t2.key5 = ‘all’) AND
…
(t1.key15 = t2.key15 OR t2.key15 = ‘all’)
```

It appears that whilst the key to key match uses the indexes, the ‘all’ search does not.

I have indexed all keys individually and compound keys (I.e [key1, key2, …]

The planner appears to still require a full table scan of table2 for each row in table1

**Further Clarification**

table2 is essentially a lookup table which is guaranteed to always return at least 1 match (based on the join) to a row in table1

keys are text e.g aaa bbb ccc (in table1) or aaa bbb ccc or all (in table2)

e.g

table1: `aaa bbb ccc` would match the following in table2 [`aaa bbb ccc`, `aaa all ccc`, `aaa all all` etc…]

Comment: Please include the full original query.

Comment: Done. Omitted the intervening keys but same from keys 1..15

Comment: Is there any constraints you can put on those columns, like the `all` can only be in key3 if it's also in key2? Or are they all completely unconstrained?

Comment: You could turn this into a series of `UNION ALL` queries, but there are 2 ^ 15 possible combinations, or 32768. So if you can limit the possible number that would help. What does jquery have to do with this?